Why do I measure a different voltage across an LED when I measure the two terminals with my multimeter vs when measuring everything related to GND?
When I measure the voltages to GND I get the following:
Anode: 3.3 V
Cathode: 1.75 V
However when I try to measure the voltage directly across it connecting the multimeter to the two terminals it reads 0 V.
What is happening here?

That's really odd... Do you have a resistor between the cathode and ground? Measuring anode to ground and getting 3.3V suggests it's reading from a GPIO I presume. Reading 0V across your two LED terminals means that's virtually no resistance across your LED.

Is the LED turned on of off? Current flowing through LED? We can't guess what scenario you are trying to measure.

probably because the LED is not connected at one end ... maybe you only think that you measured voltages at the LED

we need a circuit schematic, and a photo of the physical circuit, or a crystal ball.

Others have asked for context with good reason. I can imagine that an alternating signal source might cause measurement problems for a DC multimeter.

Here is one possibility:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
VM1 measures V1 minus the LED drop at the meter current. The LED may glow faintly, but enough to be visible in a darkened room.
VM2 measures the 3.3V supply voltage.
VM4 measures the voltage across the LED with no current flowing, so it is zero.
